# VB.net Increment variables possible?

Tags: vb.net, loops, variables, increment, do-while

I am trying to find a better way to write this code but I can't figure out how to make this cleaner.  In other languages I have used in the past I am able to increment the variables with a loop instead  of having to apply the same code to several variables.  I suppose I am looking for something like this where the variable name itself is being changed or created using the loop:

```
Dim IP0 As String = ""
    While IP0 < 5
        IP0 = IP0.Remove(index).Trim
        index = IP2.IndexOf(" "c)
        IP0 = IP0 + 1
    End While
```

In the above example, I would like the "+1" to actually add to the variable itself.  So "IP0" would become "IP1", then "IP2" and so on.  This does not compile obviously, is there a way to do this is VB.net?
  Here are a couple snippets of my current project that I would like to apply this logic to:

## 1

```
Dim IP1, IP2, IP3, IP4, IP5, IP6, IP7, IP8, IP9 As String
IP1 = IP1.Remove(index).Trim
index = IP2.IndexOf(" "c)
IP2 = IP2.Remove(index).Trim
index = IP3.IndexOf(" "c)
IP3 = IP3.Remove(index).Trim
index = IP4.IndexOf(" "c)
IP4 = IP4.Remove(index).Trim
index = IP5.IndexOf(" "c)
IP5 = IP5.Remove(index).Trim
index = IP6.IndexOf(" "c)
IP6 = IP6.Remove(index).Trim
index = IP7.IndexOf(" "c)
IP7 = IP7.Remove(index).Trim
index = IP8.IndexOf(" "c)
IP8 = IP8.Remove(index).Trim
index = IP9.IndexOf(" "c)
IP9 = IP9.Remove(index).Trim
```

## 2

```
Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\tempFiles\bigBatch.bat")

        writer.Write(
            "ping -a " & IP1 & " -n 1 > c:\tempFiles\IP1.txt" & vbNewLine &
            "ping -a " & IP2 & " -n 1 > c:\tempFiles\IP2.txt" & vbNewLine &
            "ping -a " & IP3 & " -n 1 > c:\tempFiles\IP3.txt" & vbNewLine &
            "ping -a " & IP4 & " -n 1 > c:\tempFiles\IP4.txt" & vbNewLine &
            "ping -a " & IP5 & " -n 1 > c:\tempFiles\IP5.txt" & vbNewLine &
            "ping -a " & IP6 & " -n 1 > c:\tempFiles\IP6.txt" & vbNewLine &
            "ping -a " & IP7 & " -n 1 > c:\tempFiles\IP7.txt" & vbNewLine &
            "ping -a " & IP8 & " -n 1 > c:\tempFiles\IP8.txt" & vbNewLine &
            "ping -a " & IP9 & " -n 1 > c:\tempFiles\IP9.txt" & vbNewLine)
    End Using
```

## 3

```
Dim IP1, IP2, IP3, IP4, IP5, IP6, IP7, IP8, IP9 As String
    IP1 = thisArray(3).Trim
    IP2 = thisArray(4).Trim
    IP3 = thisArray(5).Trim
    IP4 = thisArray(6).Trim
    IP5 = thisArray(7).Trim
    IP6 = thisArray(8).Trim
    IP7 = thisArray(9).Trim
    IP8 = thisArray(10).Trim
    IP9 = thisArray(11).Trim
```

Comment: Number 3 is a big hint at what you're after...

Comment: google how to make an array or list

Comment: Hmmm - why does `thisArray(3)` work? Wouldn't it be great if `IP(1)` would work?

Comment: I am familiar with arrays and lists, but how could that be applied in a loop?

Comment: This was answered below, looks like a For loop going through an array or list is the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just store your similar variables in a collection like `String()` or `List(Of String)`

```
Dim ipList As New List(Of String) From {"IP1", "IP2", "IP3", "IP4", "IP5", "IP6", "IP7", "IP8", "IP9"}

For i As Int32 = 0 To ipList.Count - 1
    Dim ip = ipList(i)
    Dim indexOfSpace = ip.IndexOf(" "c)
    If indexOfSpace >= 0 Then ipList(i) = ip.Remove(indexOfSpace)
Next
```

Comment: Ok, the For loop that goes through an array or list.  This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @user3053446: one note, if you get the `IP1`, `IP2` string variables and you want to keep them. You can also initialize the collection with the variables instead of the string literals. So f.e `Dim ipArray As String() = { IP1,IP2,IP3,... }`